# How to manipulate digits in a character string in R?

Tags: r, string

I feel like I have a super easy question but for the life of me I can't find it when googling or searching here (or I don't know the correct terms to find a solution) so here goes.

I have a large amount of text in R in which I want to identify all numbers/digits, and add a specific number to them, for example 5.

So just as a small example, if this were my text:

```
text <- c("Hi. It is 6am. I want to leave at 7am")
```

I want the output to be:

```
> text
[1] "Hi. It is 11am.  I want to leave at 12am"
```

But also I need the addition for each individual digit, so if this is the text:

```
text <- c("Hi. It is 2017. I am 35 years old.")
```

...I want the output to be:

```
> text
[1] "Hi. It is 75612. I am 810 years old."
```

I have tried 'grabbing' the numbers from the string and adding 5, but I don't know how to then get them back into the original string so I can get the full text back.

How should I go about this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do the time. I would search for a number that is followed by am or pm and then sub in a math expression to be evaluated by `gsubfn`. This is pretty flexible, but would require whole hours in its current implementation. I added an am and pm if you wanted to swap those, but I didn't try to code in detecting if the number changes from am to pm. Also note that I didn't code in rolling from 12 to 1. If you add numbers over 12, you will get a number bigger than 12.

```r
text1 <- c("Hi. It is 6am. I want to leave at 7am")
text2 <- c("It is 9am. I want to leave at 10am, but the cab comes at 11am. Can I push my flight to 12am?")

change_time <- function(text, hours, sign, am_pm){
  string_change <- glue::glue("`(\\1{sign}{hours})`{am_pm}")
  
  gsub("(\\d+)(?=am|pm)(am|pm)", string_change, text, perl = TRUE)|>
  gsubfn::fn$c()
}

change_time(text = text1, hours = 5, sign = "+", am_pm = "am")
#> [1] "Hi. It is 11am. I want to leave at 12am"

change_time(text = text2, hours = 3, sign = "-", am_pm = "pm")
#> [1] "It is 6pm. I want to leave at 7pm, but the cab comes at 8pm. Can I push my flight to 9pm?"
```

Comment: Thanks! Very insightful. Do you think it's possible to use the gsub function for the non-time digits?

Comment: yes, this was just an example for one of your texts. how would you want the other numbers changed?

Comment: I figured it out myself! (Not really by myself of course, it basically only took taking out some of your code haha, still, I'm proud) See my other post with the solution that basically works for all my texts.

Answer (score 0):

```
text1 <- c("Hi. It is 2017. I am 35 years old.")
text2 <- c("Hi. It is 6am. I want to leave at 7am")

change_number <- function(text, change, sign){   
  string_change <- glue::glue("`(\\1{sign}{change})`")
  gsub("(\\d)", string_change, text, perl = TRUE) %>%
    gsubfn::fn$c() }

change_number(text = text1, change = 5, sign = "+")
#>[1] "Hi. It is 75612. I am 810 years old."

change_number(text = text2, change = 5, sign = "+")
#>[1] "Hi. It is 11am. I want to leave at 12am"
```

This works perfectly. Many thanks to @AndS., I tweaked (or rather, simplified) your code to fit my needs better. I was determined to figure out the other text myself haha, so thanks for showing me how!

Comment: This can be simplified to `library(gsubfn); gsubfn("\\d", ~ as.numeric(x) + 5, text1)`

Answer (score 0):

Something quick and dirty with base R:

```
add_n = \(x, n, by_digit = FALSE) {
  if (by_digit) ptrn = "[0-9]" else ptrn = "[0-9]+"
  tmp       = gregexpr(ptrn, x)
  raw       = regmatches(x, gregexpr(ptrn, x))
  raw_plusn = lapply(raw, \(x) as.integer(x) + n)
  for (i in seq_along(x)) regmatches(x[i], tmp[i]) = raw_plusn[i]
  x
}

text = c(
  "Hi. It is 6am. I want to leave at 7am", 
  "wow it's 505 dollars and 19 cents",
  "Hi. It is 2017. I am 35 years old."
)

> add_n(text, 5)
# [1] "Hi. It is 11am. I want to leave at 12am"
# [2] "wow it's 510 dollars and 24 cents"      
# [3] "Hi. It is 2022. I am 40 years old."     

> add_n(text, -2)
# [1] "Hi. It is 4am. I want to leave at 5am" "wow it's 503 dollars and 17 cents"    
# [3] "Hi. It is 2015. I am 33 years old."   

> add_n(text, 5, by_digit = TRUE)
# [1] "Hi. It is 11am. I want to leave at 12am"
# [2] "wow it's 10510 dollars and 614 cents"   
# [3] "Hi. It is 75612. I am 810 years old."
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
data.frame(text) %>%
  # separate `text` into individual characters:
  separate_rows(text,  sep = "(?<!^)(?!$)") %>% 
  # add `5` to any digit:
  mutate(
           # if you detect a digit...
    text = ifelse(str_detect(text, "\\d"),
           # ... extract it, convert it to numeric, add `5`:
           as.numeric(str_extract(text, "\\d")) + 5,
           # ... else leave `text` as is:
           text)
    ) %>% 
  # string the characters back together:
  summarise(text = str_c(text, collapse = ""))
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  text                                   
  <chr>                                  
1 Hi. It is 11am. I want to leave at 12am
```

Data 1:

```
text <- c("Hi. It is 6am. I want to leave at 7am")
```

Note that the same code works for the second `text` as well without any change:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  text                                
  <chr>                               
1 Hi. It is 75612. I am 810 years old.
```

Data 2:

```
text <- c("Hi. It is 2017. I am 35 years old.")
```